# SyntaxError in print() Python3.2?

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x

I'm getting this error in Python3.2 on a simple print statement. I'm going through some tutorials, and this is exactly the code example is written:

```
fh = open('lines.txt')
for line in fh.readlines():
   print(line, end="")
```

But this is what i get

```
File "./forloop.py", line 5
    print(line, end="")
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in the comment, I'm quite sure you are on 2.x.

Try this

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

If that doesn't give you an error, and says "2.x" then you are certainly. using 2.x

If it gives you a syntax error, its "3.x"

(besides the obvious task of checking what sys.version holds, "print sys.version" is valid 2.x syntax but not valid 3.x syntax)

Comment: Yeah, see my comment above to Ignacio :( How do I get it to use 3.2 when i know it's installed?

Comment: Check /usr/local/bin .. it might be installed there.

Answer (score 4):

That error is generated by Python 2.x. Be sure that you are actually invoking 3.x, whether via command line or via shebang.

Comment: I can confirm what Ignacio is saying. Python 3.1 and 3.2 do NOT give the error, but 2.7 does. Oscar must be running this in Python 2.x as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Whats a command i can put in my .py file to show what version is running? should be 3...

Comment: crap yeah 2.6.1 with import sys; print(sys.version). But how do I know, on a Mac, where my 3.2 install is? I KNOW it exists, just not where. My she-bang is: `#! /usr/bin/pythonw` with just `#!` its Python 2.5

Comment: Err... both produce bad interpreter errors. I installed with the Mac OS X bundle from python.org

Comment: Found it! /usr/local/bin/python3